# Why am I getting the last octet repeated when my Perl program outputs a UTF-8 encoded string in cmd.exe?

Tags: c, windows, perl, utf-8

#### Update

As @ikegami suggested, I reported this as a bug.

[Bug #121783 for perl5: Windows: UTF-8 encoded output in cmd.exe with code page 65001 causes unexpected output](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=121783)

Consider the following C and Perl programs which both output a the UTF-8 encoding of the string "αβγ" on standard output:

#### C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    /* UTF-8 encoded alpha, beta, gamma */
    char x[] = { 0xce, 0xb1, 0xce, 0xb2, 0xce, 0xb3, 0x00 };
    puts(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\…> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\…> cttt.exe
αβγ
```

#### Perl version:

```
C:\…>  perl -e "print qq{\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3\n}"
αβγ
�
```

From what I can tell, the last octet, `0xb3` is being output again, on another line, which is being translated to `U+FFFD`.

Note that redirecting output eliminates this effect.

I can also verify that it is the last octet being repeated:

```
C:\…>  perl -e "print qq{\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3xyz\n}"
αβγxyz
z
```

On the other hand, [syswrite](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html) avoids this problem.

```
C:\…>  perl -e "syswrite STDOUT, qq{\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3xyz\n}"
αβγxyz
```

I have observed this in cmd.exe windows on Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit and Windows Vista Home 32-bit using both self-built perl 5.18.2 and ActiveState's 5.16.3.

I do not see the problem in Cygwin, Linux, or Mac OS X environments. Also, Cygwin's perl 5.14.4 produces correct output in cmd.exe.

Also, when the code page is set to 437, the output from both the C and the Perl versions is identical:

```
C:\…> chcp 437
Active code page: 437

C:\…> cttt.exe
╬▒╬▓╬│

C:\…>  perl -e "print qq{\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3\n}"
╬▒╬▓╬│
```

What is causing the last octet to be output twice when printing from perl program in cmd.exe when the [code page is set to 65001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

PS: I have some more information and screenshots on [my blog](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/05/utf-8-ouput-from-perl-and-c-programs-in.html). For this question, I have tried to distill everything to the simplest possible cases.

PPS: Leaving out the `\n` results in something even more interesting:

```
C:\…> perl -e "print qq{\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3xyz}"
αβγxyzxyz
```

```
C:\…> perl -e "print qq{\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3}"
αβγ�γ�
```

Comment: My guess: a bug somewhere in the windows shell.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Given that both the C version and `syswrite` work as expected, I suspect it is an interaction between Perl's `:crlf` IO layer and code page 65001. But, I do not know exactly where to look. Pointers welcome.

Comment: Submit a bug report using `perlbug`

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `\n` ?

Comment: Does `stdout`, in text mode on windows, translate the `'\n`\ into `"\r\n"`?  Have no idea how that would explain this, but another thought.

Comment: @ikegami I will submit a bug report, but I want to check a few things. In the mean time, if we figure this out, and we can submit a patch, it would be even better.

Comment: Note that the newline thing is a red herring ... The `puts` adds and if I pipe output through `xxd` I get the exact sequence of octets for both the C and Perl versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following program produces the correct output:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);

binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:encoding(utf8):crlf");

print 'αβγxyz', "\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\…> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
C:\…> perl pttt.pl
αβγxyz
```

which seems to indicate to me there is some funkiness with the `:crlf` layer. I do not understand the internals enough to comment intelligently about this at this point.

After many experiments, I have come to the conclusion that, if the console is already set to 65001 code page, `binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:encoding(utf8):crlf");` will "work". However, note the following:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:encoding(utf8):crlf");
print Dump [
    map {
        my $x = defined($_) ? $_ : '';
        $x =~ s/\A([0-9]+)\z/sprintf '0x%08x', $1/eg;
        $x;
    } PerlIO::get_layers(STDOUT, details => 1)
];
print "αβγxyz\n";
```

gives me:

```
---
- unix
- ''
- 0x01205200
- crlf
- ''
- 0x00c85200
- unix
- ''
- 0x01201200
- encoding
- utf8
- 0x00c89200
- crlf
- ''
- 0x00c8d200
αβγxyz
```

As before, I do not know enough to know the full consequences of this. I do intend to build a debug `perl` at some point to further diagnose this.

I [examined this a little further](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/05/utf-8-output-from-perl-in-cmdexe-layers.html). Here are some observations from that post:

The flags for the first `unix` layer are `0x01205200 = CANWRITE | TRUNCATE | CRLF | OPEN | NOTREG`. Why is `CRLF` set for the `unix` layer on Windows? I do not know about the internals enough to understand this.

However, the flags for the second `unix` layer, the one pushed by my explicit `binmode`, are 0x01201200 = 0x01205200 & ~CRLF. This is what would have made sense to me to begin with.

The flags for the first crlf layer are `0x00c85200 = CANWRITE | TRUNCATE | CRLF | LINEBUF | FASTGETS | TTY`. The flags for the second `layer`, which I push after the `:encoding(utf8)` layer are `0x00c8d200 = 0x00c85200 | UTF8`.

Now, if I open a file using `open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', 'ttt'`, and dump the same information, I get:

```
---
- unix
- ''
- 0x00201200
- crlf
- ''
- 0x00405200
- encoding
- utf8
- 0x00409200
```

As expected, the `unix` layer does not set the `CRLF` flag.

Comment: You may want to try my PerlIO::Layers instead of using PerlIO::get_layers, it gives much more friendly output.

Comment: A bug in the `:crlf` layer? surely you jest.  /s

Comment: @Ether It looks to me like a bug in the unix layer on Windows when output is to cmd.exe. But, I can't figure out why [PERLIO_F_CRLF is getting set on the bottom-most unix layer](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/05/why-is-perliofcrlf-set-on-bottom-most.html).