# Perso-Arabic Characters are not correctly shown on the command-line

Tags: command-prompt, strawberry-perl, perl

I am trying to run a simple perl code that uses Persian/Arabic characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "سلام";
```

I am using strawberry perl on Windows 7. When I fire up the command line and execute the program, the message shown is garbled. The encoding should be utf-8 to get the message rendered correctly.

So I figured if I use the `chcp 65001` command, the problem will be resolved. Unfortunately that didn't help and I still have the same problem.

I tried rewriting the beginning lines to get the correct encoding:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

print "سلام";
```

Then I ran perl on command-line and first executed the line `chcp 65001` and then ran the program. Here's what I got:

[image]

Comment: I did try adding "use utf8;" to the beginning of the script. Unfortunately the command-line can not display the text correctly.

Comment: May I know exactly what part of my question is vague? I want to be able to view the output text (which consists of Perso-Arabic characters) shown correctly in the command-line after I run the code. Right now I only get gibberish.

Comment: If the file is UTF-8 encoded, you both need to `use utf8` to declare the source encoding, but also mark the output streams so that they encode anything that's printed from Unicode to whatever encoding your command line uses. The “wide character in print” warning tells us that you didn't declare an encoding for STDOUT. So adding a `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)'` (or whatever encoding your command line uses) should fix the problem. If your CL does not use an Unicode encoding (e.g. like UTF-16BE), then we are in trouble as the target encoding probably does not support Arabic characters.

Comment: @novice66 You seem to be using raster fonts. In addition to making sure the codepage is correct, and you are outputting in the correct encoding, you also need to make sure you are using a TrueType font capable of displaying the characters you want.

Comment: The above comment by Sinan Ünür is the real answer to your question. What he actually posted as an answer is an answer to a question you haven't asked yet.

Comment: Yes, we discussed the issue at the comments section of his post in more detail. The point was that the problem had nothing to do with perl. I followed his suggestion of using ConEmu and that solved the problem. He edited his answer to include that in the main response too. So I chose that as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416075/) and [blog posts](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/05/utf-8-ouput-from-perl-and-c-programs-in.html) culminating in [Why is PERLIO_F_CRLF set on the bottom-most 'unix' layer on Windows?](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/05/why-is-perliofcrlf-set-on-bottom-most.html).

A work-around seems to be to use `binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:encoding(utf8):crlf");` to undo the fact that when output is to a `cmd.exe` window (and only in that case) the bottom-most 'unix' layer has the CRLF flag set (in direct contradiction to [perliol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perliol.html)).

Instead of `cmd.exe`, you can use [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) which has a lot of nice features and makes it really easy to set up a custom font (in addition to individual tabs with private settings etc).

Don't let what happens in `cmd.exe` dictate anything.

Comment: I replaced binmode `STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';` with `binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:encoding(utf8):crlf");`. Saved it and reloaded the cmd and typed the `chcp 65001` before running the program again. Unfortunately I am still getting the exact same result as before.

Comment: You also need to use a font that is capable of displaying the actual characters.

Comment: Ok, so I right-clicked on the console and checked the fonts. I am using "raster fonts". There are two other options Lucida console and Consolas. When I set the font to any of those, I get empty boxes instead of those weird characters. I now tried adding a Perso-arabic friendly font by editing string values in regedit and rebooted but I don't see new fonts appear in the list.

Comment: At least I think I now know what is the source of the problem, but this is kind of frustrating as it was my first day of trying to learn perl.

Comment: Try rebooting. The display issue has nothing to do with Perl. And, `perl` will output everything correctly to a file. If you want a console with lots more features than `cmd.exe`, try [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/). Much easier to set a custom font as well. As a side benefit, you won't notice the issue I mentioned and you will be able to write portable code without resorting to `binmode STDOUT, ':unix:encoding(utf8):crlf'`. Instead, use [Tom's preamble](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html). Don't let what happens in cmd.exe dictate anything.