# How to properly print wide chars in cmd.exe under chcp 65001 using python?

Tags: python, unicode, cmd

This looks like a Python issue because using python print or call subprocess with cmd echo, I can get different results.(See examples in below)

The question is how to properly print wide chars in cmd.exe under chcp65001?
Is there an option in python print method or any special methods I need to do to adapt the Windows environment.

OS Win7 64bit.

```
==GOOD==

C:\>python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.run('cmd.exe /c echo 啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊', shell=True)"
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊

==BAD==
C:\> python -c "print('啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊')"
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
�啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
��啊啊啊啊啊啊
�啊啊啊
�啊

C:\>chcp
Active code page: 65001

C:\>python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

[image]

There is already a Perl base fix:

```
C:\>python -c "print('啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊')" | perl -Mutf8 -ne "BEGIN{binmode(STDIN,':unix:encoding(utf8):crlf');binmode(STDOUT, ':unix:encoding(utf8):crlf');}print"
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊

C:\>chcp
Active code page: 65001
```

[Why am I getting the last octet repeated when my Perl program outputs a UTF-8 encoded string in cmd.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416075/why-am-i-getting-the-last-octet-repeated-when-my-perl-program-outputs-a-utf-8-en)

It would be good to have the Python Solution
[image]

Comment: Not reproduced with Python 3.6.4 + Win10, although the display of the command is partly shown before execution.

Comment: [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console#win-unicode-console)  A Python package to enable Unicode input and display when running Python from Windows console.

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for the sharing. Since I have updated the Python version already, the module seems not needed any more(see the "issue" in the github).